# SQL Syntax Issue with getting sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, syntax

Ok I have two tables.

Table IDAssoc has the columns`bill_id`, `year`, `area_id`.

Table Bill has the columns `bill_id`, `year`, `main_id`, and `amount_due`.

I'm trying to get the sum of the `amount_due` column from the bill table for each of the associated area_ids in the IDAssoc table.

I'm doing a select statement to select the sum and joining on the bill_ids. How can I set this up so it will have a single row for each of the associated bills in each area_id from the assoc table. There may be three or four bill_ids associated with each area_id and I need those summed for each and returned so I can use this select in another statement. I have a group by set up for the area_id but it still is returning each row and not summing them up for each area_id. I have the year and main_id specified already in the where clause to return the data that I want, but I can't get the sum to work properly. Sorry I'm still learning and I'm not sure how to do this. Thanks!

Edit- Basically the query I'm trying so far is basically just like the one posted below:

```
select a.area_id, sum(b.amount_due)
from IDAssoc a
inner join Bill b
on a.bill_id = b.bill_id
where Bill.year = 2006 and bill.bill_id = 11111
```

These are just arbitrary numbers.
The data this is returning is like this:
amount_due  -     area_id
.05                 1003
.15                 1003
.11                 1003
65                  1004
55                  1004

I need one row returned for each area_id with the amount_due summed. The area_id is only in the assoc table and not in the bill table.

Comment: You might want to post any SQL you've tried so far.

Comment: Can you show your current data and desired results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select a.area_id, sum(b.amount_due)
from IDAssoc a
inner join Bill b
on a.bill_id = b.bill_id
where b.year = 2006 and b.bill_id = 11111
group by a.area_id
```

You might want to change `inner join` to `left join` if one `IDAssoc` can have many or no `Bill`:

```
select a.area_id, coalesce(sum(b.amount_due),0)
from IDAssoc a
left join Bill b
on a.bill_id = b.bill_id
where b.year = 2006 and b.bill_id = 11111
group by a.area_id
```

Comment: That is still returning separate rows and not summing up my data. It needs to sum all the bills in each area_id and return it in a single row with the associated area_id. This is returning, for example, 4 rows with arbitrary amounts and the same area_id when it should be one row and one area_id. In reality there are 4-5 different area_ids that need to have the multiple bills associated summed.

Comment: The left join also did not help, still returns multiple rows for each area_id when they should be summed.

Comment: My mistake, I missed out the `group by` clause

Comment: That worked, I actually had the right query but I included the amount in the group by and that messed it up. I'm still learning and that makes sense now, but thanks for helping me to get to that point. It's working now.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT a.area_id, SUM(b.amount_due) TotalAmount
FROM IDAssoc a
LEFT JOIN Bill b
ON a.bill_id = b.bill_id
GROUP BY a.area_id
```

Comment: I have a group by, I included the amount due in the group by along with the area id and that messed it up, when I took that out of the group by my original query worked. Thank you for your help so I could figure this out.